# Location of log file in the server

Tags: java, logging

I have created logs for my project in a log file. I have provided the location of log file as 'logs/LogFile.log' in the java code. When run on a local server(Tomcat or Websphere), a new folder named 'logs' is created in the classpath of the server and i can find the 'LogFile.log' with logs in it.

Now my project is converted to EAR and it is up in the Dev Server. Where will my log file be created? How can i see those logs?

Comment: what is the Dev Server?

Comment: Its a develeopment server. Its a kind of external server. We can only perform transactions in SOAPUI for the project uploaded in the Dev server. It will not create any local files in the machine.

Comment: what server it is? is it Apache Tomcat? ApacheKaraf? or something else what is it?

Comment: it is websphere application server (WAS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a local server, the logs will be appended in the destined log file, which will be in the server installed directory or a remote user created directory.

In case of a remote server, say Unix server, the logs will be generated in the specified location inside the server. We need to login to the unix server via putty or Techtia and can view the logs in the specified locations.